# how to stop dialog window from getting hidden behind other windows- Mainwindow, loginwindow and dialogbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

All coders there,
before marking this duplicate, read till the last line.

I am getting issue of dialog box getting hidden under main application window.
I have checked all the parameters i.e. Topmost and Owner to make dialog box appear.
Finally I found my problem lies within the owner as owner is wrong.

here is my pseudo:

- when someone clicks on exe,open the login window(I have a different project,
  login.dll)
- after login is successful, launch main window(this is my actual
  mainwindow, mainwindow.dll)
- now somewhere after launching main window , I launch popup(third
  window -this is separate error handling project, errorhandler.dll)

**Issue:**
error popup do not appear and gets hidden after other windows.

**My code:**

```
                   if (popupWindow.Owner == null) && popupWindow != System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)
                {
                    popupWindow.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
                }
```

**What I found:**
When I debug the code, what I've observed - login window becomes  current.Mainwindow as it was launched first. After login I just hide the window and not closing it. Now, after successful logon I launch Main window(which is active window, not actual main window :),confusing )

After this, when popup appears, above mentioned code is getting executed and strangely **System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow**
holds the value of Login window and setting owner to login window which makes popup hidden behind other windows.

- I can't close login window directly after successful logon, as it
  will terminate the application because my main window is taking 2-3
  minutes to load(tremendous stuffs to load)
  How to set the main window as *System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow* because once loading of main window finishes , popup starts appearing on the next second.??

How to remove login window from the *System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows* list?

Is there any shortcut method by which we can set active window on *System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow* and refer it everytime?

Comment: why not launch main window first, then login window showdialog?

Comment: Actually, my main window takes 2-3 minutes of loading. hence , to improve user experience I put first logon, if successful, then make users wait, if fails, they can close it within seconds and re-launch again.

Comment: why not use multi-threading in main window

Comment: You need to open your main window, start loading asynchronously, mark your UI as loading (lots of loading indicators out there you can use), then launch your login window modally.

Comment: I can't use threatening as i don't want mainwindow to run until and unless login is successful

Comment: *threading, i mean

Answer (score 0):

> - when someone clicks on exe,open the login window(I have a different project, login.dll)
> - after login is successful, launch main window(this is my actual mainwindow, mainwindow.dll)

```
 Application.Current.MainWindow = MyNewMainWindow;
```

> - now somewhere after launching main window , I launch popup(third window -this is separate error handling project, errorhandler.dll)

Comment: I know this is what I've to do(as it is pretty straightforward to do so), but having said that the situation I am facing where I get the control after 3 windows opened. Threading can't help. I am expecting some logic where I can put your line. :) Thanks heaps!